# Set up filtering when using mat-table generated by schematic

Tags: angular, angular-material

Problem: Can not set up filtering using material documentation when using a generated schematic. Seems to be a problem with extending a datasource instead of a `mattabledatasource`.

Steps to reproduce:
You will need the Angular CLI

1. `ng new table-project --style scss --routing` (sets up project)
2. code table-project (opens folder)
3. `ng add @angular/material` (adds angular material)
4. `ng generate @angular/material:material-table --name table` (generates table schematic, include this in app component)

After this point, I can't set up filtering because filter function is not exposed because it is extending a generic data source instead of mattabledatasource. How to fix this?